# Free UML Drawing Tools

Tags: objective-c, uml

What are the best free uml drawing tools?

All the ones I have found require membership payments and only offer limited functionality based to public users on a trial basis...rubbish!

Comment: I look forward to seeing the high-quality products you produce for free.

Comment: I am a student-no budget...No one said high quality anyway. I need export functionality...READ THE QUESTION BUDDY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my (very simple) needs I used [ArgoUML](http://argouml.tigris.org/). I'm not an expert about, but I found it enough easy to use. It's open source and, on the web page, you can find a good user guide.

Comment: Hi. I have starte dto use this but I cannot find a way to add required/provided relationships in my component diagrams...any clues?

Comment: After a year of usage of ArgoUML i have to say, it's not the solution that makes real fun to use. I'm going back to a simple drawing tool like Visio.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at StarUML ( http://staruml.sourceforge.net/en/ )

It's free, open source, and incredibly fully featured.

For a full list, check out the ones marked as Open Source here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools

But I'd really recommend StarUML!

Answer (score 1):

For my first two software engineering courses, I used the stand alone version of [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/), but it is just for diagrams.  It exports to standard graphics, or pdf.  They also have an eclipse plugin version, but I never used it.

Answer (score 0):

For a no frill drawing tool, I find Google Docs (drawings) pretty good.  Note that printing works better under Mozilla than Chrome, strangely enough.  In Chrome, I cannot get dashed lines to print.

Answer (score -1):

Try [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com). Supports Eclipse IDE.

Comment: freemind is a great mindmapping product but it doesn't do UML.